# Tech-ed Berlin and lack of SharePoint sessions

Tags: community

Sadly I can't to to SPC. but I did get a ticked to Tech-ed. But i'm sad by the lack of SharePoint sessions. Do you think we will get anymore or is the session list now complete?

Is the SharePoint product team doing a SharePoint event at Tech-ed?

MVP's need Rest?! surely not, How would I get a SharePoint event going in berlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole whack of SharePoint 2010 in depth sessions at TechEd Berlin trust me, I'll be speaking there on the topic myself. The reason why you can't see them is because of the NDA that is still up until the 19th of this month. You will see SharePoint 2010 sessions pouring in towards the end of this month.
This is definitely a very good substitute for SPC09 as most if not all of the apects of the new SharePoint 2010 will be covered that are going to be covered at SPC09 so get ready to soak it all in.

No one is rsting trust me, we're all hard at work :)
I got two other conferences where I'll be presenting afterwards, Slovenia one above and Microsoft one in Middle East.
No rest for the wicked!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint speakers will probably be resting after SPC 2009 :))) Teched conference is general one and needs to cover all the products. Maybe this link might help you if you want to meet some MVPs and discuss stuff: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/meet-teched-europe-2009/

There is dedicated SharePoint Conference in Slovenia also coming up in November 2009. http://www.sharepointkonferenca.si/ENG/default.aspx